# My Sony Vegas keeps crashing on running it

Tags: vegas-pro

This is a very frustrating problem:

My Sony Vegas 13.0 crashes instantaniously after running it. It doesn't even show the loading splash screen. It gives this error message:

```
Problem Description
Application Name: Vegas Pro
Application Version: Version 13.0 (Build 453) 64-bit
Problem: Unmanaged Exception (0xc0000005)
Fault Module: C:\Program Files\Sony\Vegas Pro 13.0\vegas130.exe
Fault Address: 0x00007FF72E7DA710
Fault Offset: 0x000000000081A710

Fault Process Details
Process Path: C:\Program Files\Sony\Vegas Pro 13.0\vegas130.exe
Process Version: Version 13.0 (Build 453) 64-bit
Process Description: Vegas Pro
Process Image Date: 2015-06-05 (Fri Jun 05) 13:53:04
```

I have no idea why it suddenly started doing this. Maybe it has something to do with my recent Windows 10 update. The same thing is happening with Sony Vegas 12.0

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a bug report and not an actual question. Check your drivers and report this to Sony instead.